# Best practice for handling different datasets with same type of data but different column names

Tags: r, data.table

For example, suppose I want to build a package for analyzing customer transactions. In a nice world, every transactions dataset would look like

```
   TransactionId CustomerId TransactionDate
1:             1          1      2017-01-01
2:             2          2      2017-01-15
3:             3          1      2017-05-20
4:             4          3      2017-06-11
```

Then I could make nice functions like

```
num_customers <- function(transactions){
  length(unique(transactions$CustomerId))
}
```

In reality, the column names people use vary.  (E.g. "CustomerId", "CustomerID", and "cust_id" might all be used by different companies).

My question is, what is the best way for me to deal with this?  I plan on relying heavily on data.table, so my instinct was do make the users provide a mapping from their column names to the ones I use as an attribute of their table like

```
mytransactions <- data.table(
  transaction_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
  customer_id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
  transaction_date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-15", "2017-05-20", "2017-06-11"))
)
setattr(
  mytransactions, 
  name = "colmap",
  value = c(TransactionID="transaction_id", CustomerID="customer_id", TransactionDate="transaction_date")
)
attributes(mytransactions)
```

However, unfortunately, as soon as they subset their data this attribute gets removed.

```
attributes(mytransactions[1:2])
```

Comment: With `data.frame` objects when programming use `transactions[["CustomerId"]]`,  not `transactions$CustomerId`. Like this you can have the function use a character value as an argument. Something like `num_customers <- function(transactions, custid)`. (BTW, there's a typo in your function definition, it's not `functions` with 's'.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks, but I don't see that as a practical solution for a package with many functions, especially since it would require the user to input a column-name mapping for every single function.  This could make the user's code unnecessarily long and repetitive.

Comment: That's the downside of it, but it's generally considered best pratice when programming. It is suggested that the `$` operator should be left for interactive use only.

Comment: Make the user submit a "customers table" (separate from the transactions table) with a key column you can grab the name of with `key(custDT)`..? Maybe you could have them create a database-like object (well, a `list` of tables) containing both the customers and transactions tables and have functions take that object as input.

Comment: iYou could create an input box where your user selects a file and then another pop asks the name for each of the three fields in your database, which you save into a variableas key=values that gets used to rename the columns right after import.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect data to have a specific shape and set of attributes, define a class. It's really easy to do in R using the S3 system, since you only need to change the `class` attribute.

The best way to let users create S3 objects is through a function. To keep the original "feel" of adapting existing datasets, have the users provide a dataset and name which columns to use for different values. Default argument values can keep your package code succinct and reward standards-respecting users.

```
transaction_table <- function(dataset,
                              cust_id    = "CustomerId",
                              trans_id   = "TransactionId",
                              trans_date = "TransactionDate") {
  keep_columns <- c(
    CustomerId      = cust_id,
    TransactionId   = trans_id,
    TransactionDate = trans_date
  )
  out_table <- dataset[, keep_columns, with = FALSE]
  setnames(out_table, names(keep_columns))
  setattr(out_table, "class", c("transaction_table", class(out_table)))
  out_table
}


standardized <- transaction_table(
  mytransactions,
  cust_id    = "customer_id",
  trans_id   = "transaction_id",
  trans_date = "transaction_date"
)
standardized
#    CustomerId TransactionId TransactionDate
# 1:          1             1      2017-01-01
# 2:          2             2      2017-01-15
# 3:          1             3      2017-05-20
# 4:          3             4      2017-06-11
```

As a bonus, you can now take full advantage of the S3 system, defining class-specific methods for generic functions.

```
print.transaction_table <- function(x, ...) {
  time_range <- range(standardized[["TransactionDate"]])
  formatted_range <- strftime(time_range)
  cat("Transactions from", formatted_range[1], "to", formatted_range[2], "\n")
  NextMethod()
}


print(standardized)
# Transactions from 2017-01-01 to 2017-06-11 
#    CustomerId TransactionId TransactionDate
# 1:          1             1      2017-01-01
# 2:          2             2      2017-01-15
# 3:          1             3      2017-05-20
# 4:          3             4      2017-06-11
```